# Calculating percentage of numeric values on Postgres with leading zero, how to avoid division zero?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have cryptocurrencies transactions in my postgres and i would like to calculate the percentage change of current price/first(price) but i got division zero. Also, the price of the assets in my table could have the actual value of $0.0020 meaning with lots of zeros. Can I avoid that and actually get the percentage difference?

Comment: Use `nullif()` to turn zero into a null

Comment: For example if a token has the value of 0.020 and I need to calculate the percentage difference of that token’s price an hour ago, it’ll still show zero division. Is there no way to calculate it?

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example to reproduce this? Using the `NUMERIC` type, `FLOAT`,  or `DOUBLE PRECISION` I cannot reproduce your issue unless explicitly using `0.0`... this includes dividing by something like `0.00000000000000000000001` . Makes me believe you are truly dividing by zero.